# Open iFrame in parent Window

Tags: javascript, iframe, window.open

I have a page that has WebParts contained in it.  One of the WebParts is an iFrame.  Within this iFrame, the user can search for records and a grid is populated.  They can then click on the results to open up a new iFrame with all of the details.  The problem I have is that the iFrame is too big for the hosting iFrame and it looks messy.  What I'd like to do is open the new iFrame in the hosting page (same domain) in a Modal Dialog box but can't get this to work.  I've tried all sorts of variations of:

```
parent.window.CreateModalDialog
window.parent.CreateModelDialog
parent.parent.window.CreateModalDialog
```

but I can never get back to the main page to open the new iFrame in a new window.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Both the IFrame and parent should be on same domain unless you can't access parent's document. Other way to do it is [post messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). You can create a  function to create dialog on the parent page in parent's document and call the function.